# Weights of finite abelian group actions on submanifolds/subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

(cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125529/weights-of-finite-abelian-group-actions-on-submanifolds-subvarieties)

How do weights associated to actions of finite subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on submanifolds/subvarieties of $X \subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ relate to those on all of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (covered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082234/the-weights-of-the-induced-mathbb-c-action-on-the-tangent-space-to-mathbb for case of $\mathbb{P}^n$)?

In principle, it doesn't seem that complicated (at least for simple examples) since we're taking the inverse of the Jacobian of the map $\rho(g) : X \longrightarrow X$ (pre)composed with (inverses of) charts in $\mathbb{C}^r$ for appropriate $r$. However, I've been confused about some examples I've read about.

In the case of cyclic subgroups coming from (primitive) roots of unity, the action of the cyclic group generated by the $p^{\text{th}}$ root of unity on $(w^p = f(x, y, z)) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ ($\deg f = p$) with the action $(w : x : y : z) \mapsto (\zeta w : x : y : z)$ with $\zeta$ the primitive $p^{\text{th}}$ root of unity for some odd prime $p$, I've seen a claim that the weights associated to this action on the subset $w = 0$ are $p - 1, 0$. This is coming from the induced linear map from the tangent plane to some fixed point to itself. It seems different from what I would have expected from the $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Another thing I'm confused about was a claim (for smooth projective varieties) was that the dimension of irreducible components of fixed loci (for finite abelian subgroups in general) gives the number of $0$-weights. Where does this come from? Testing this on projective space, this only seems to occur if we have equality of starting weights.

It seems I'm probably missing some things on how the specific charts would affect the Jacobian involved. Does this means that there is no simple way to relate weights associated with actions on specified hypersurfaces to their intersections (say assuming that the intersection is complete)?